# Representing binary functions with a finite gate set without exponential blow-up?

Tags: logic, circuits, boolean-algebra

It is pretty well taught that any binary function can be represented using CNF. But conversion to CNF can take an exponential number of gates. The truth table is exponentially sized relative to the number of input variables.

Is there any form of representing truth tables that requires only a polynomial or quasipolynomial number of gates? I know there are ones that preserve satisfiability, not equality---but is there anything that preserves equality?

Comment: What exactly is the input form of your "binary function"?

Comment: Are you asking for a *canonical* form where you can compare the equality of functions in linear time (wrt the size of that form)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  No matter what representation of functions as circuits/formulas you use, there will exist some functions that require exponential size to represent.  This was proven by Shannon in 1949.  See [Shannon's result that some Boolean functions require exponential circuits](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151372/755).

Intuitively, you can count the number of circuits/formulas of polynomial size, and it is much less than the number of functions.